# Issue when compare a value in column with number

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a issue, i do not know this is bug or not, could you please help to analyze problem.
My table hs a column ‘contents’ with type ‘varchar’.
when i insert value to this column (ex: xyz x#1, y, z can be any number) then i do query

```
$this->find()->where([‘content >’ => ‘20’])->toArray();
```

The query will return xyz for me. that is my expectation.
but when i insert value like 1yz (y, z can be any number) then i do query

```
$this->find()->where([‘content >’ => ‘20’])->toArray();
```

The query will return empty array.
I have tried with many value like 123; 145; 134; 1678 but it returned same result.
Do you had the same situation? please give me an advice.
Thank you very much.
(Ps: i have tried with cakephp 3.6 and cakephp 1.2)

Comment: When comparing strings, anything starting with x will be greater than 20, but anything starting with 1 will be less. That's the "problem" that you're seeing? It's simply how string comparison works.

Comment: I have fount the answer, firstly, cakephp will compare x with 2, if x > 2 then it return xyz < 2k, it apply the same with continuos number.
So if when i compare 1235 < 21 then return true;
235 < 21 return false
642 < 65 return true;

Comment: Its not depend on cakephp comparison its all about how your database sever data compare for `varchar` type.

Comment: > `I have fount the answer` - Please do not answer questions with comments. That said - that is not how CakePHP works; CakePHP's responsibilities are only to generate a query, and the DB is what is interpreting that. I think you should ask yourself what `SELECT * from some_table WHERE content > "20"` on a string field is supposed to mean

Comment: Actually when i ran the query SELECT * from some_table WHERE content > "20", it returned all data in some_table (include string value in 'contents' column), i am not sure it is cause of database or cakephp.